# connection closed without response error because of external API call

Tags: node.js, performance, asynchronous, heroku

I have a route where a user can post information for external webpage they want to save. Like the page title, URL, and image url for the page- similar to pinterest.

When my server gets this information (title, url, and image url), my server does a GET request for the image url to the external site. When my server gets the image data back, it crops and stores it on AWS and stores the link in a new mongo document with the other web page info and sends the response with this document back to the client.

As my production web app grows sometimes these image requests cause a H13 error on heroku. Even with a 6 second timeout set on the image request, I'm still getting a "connection closed without response" error in production maybe because other parts of the request are long too or it's a particularly busy moment in time on the site.

I feel like getting the image in the request and waiting for it to load in order to send a response to the client is maybe the wrong way to go about this. Is there a way to handle this request that will work better while my web app scales?

Not sure if this question doesn't belong on stackoverflow because maybe it's opinionated. But I'm not sure if there is a standard way to go about this and I'm just a newb.